# Android Studio tells me to use locale variables

Tags: android, textview

In my Activity I'm creating many TextViews in the onCreate method. All TextViews are declared as private class variables. But I'm not using theses TextViews only in the onCreate method rather in another method. So I don't understand the warning.

```
public class ActAchievement extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvAchieve1;
    private TextView tvAchieve2;
    private TextView tvAchieve3;
    private TextView tvAchieve4;
    private TextView tvAchieve5;
    private TextView tvAchieve6;
    private TextView tvAchieveSub2;
    private TextView tvAchieveSub3;
    private TextView tvAchieveSub4;
    private TextView tvAchieveSub5;
    private TextView tvAchieveSub6;
    private TextView tvCurrentRank;
    private TextView tvCurrentQuestions;
    private int correctQuestions;
    private Cursor questionCursor;
    private String currentRank;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_achievement);

        tvCurrentRank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_current_rank);
        tvCurrentQuestions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_current_questions);
        tvAchieve1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_achieve1);
        tvAchieve2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_achieve2);
        tvAchieve3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_achieve3);
        tvAchieve4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_achieve4);
        tvAchieve5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_achieve5);
        tvAchieve6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_achieve6);
        tvAchieveSub2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_achieve_sub2);
        tvAchieveSub3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_achieve_sub3);
        tvAchieveSub4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_achieve_sub4);
        tvAchieveSub5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_achieve_sub5);
        tvAchieveSub6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_achieve_sub6);

        currentRank = getResources().getString(R.string.currentRank);

        detectRank();
    }

    public void detectRank() {
        questionCursor = MyDatabase.getInstance(this).getCorrectQuestions();
        correctQuestions = questionCursor.getInt(questionCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow((MyDatabase.ResultColumns.CORRECT)));

        tvCurrentRank.setText(currentRank + " " + tvAchieve1.getText());
        tvCurrentQuestions.setText(correctQuestions + "/255");

        if (correctQuestions >= 5) {
            setRank(tvAchieve2, tvAchieveSub2);
        }

        if (correctQuestions >= 10) {
            setRank(tvAchieve3, tvAchieveSub3);
        }

        if (correctQuestions >= 150) {
            setRank(tvAchieve4, tvAchieveSub4);
        }

        if (correctQuestions >= 200) {
            setRank(tvAchieve5, tvAchieveSub5);
        }

        if (correctQuestions == 255) {
            setRank(tvAchieve6, tvAchieveSub6);
        }
    }

    public void setRank(TextView tvAchieve, TextView tvAchieveSub) {
        tvCurrentRank.setText(currentRank + " " + tvAchieve.getText());
        tvAchieve.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
        tvAchieveSub.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
    }
}
```

If I changed the variables to member variables in the onCreate method so I have to call the second method with all the TextViews as arguments.

Do you understand what Android Studio means with the message?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are chances where these warnings to be wrong. Take it as a suggestion. You must act manually. You can either accept it or suppress it if it won't work for your case.